# What is the point of If-Unmodified-Since/If-Modified-Since? Aren't they superseded by ETags?

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, etag, if-modified-since

There seem to be two distinct ways to implement conditional requests using HTTP headers, both of which can be used for caching, range requests, concurrency control etc...:

1. **If-Unmodified-Since and If-Modified-Since**, where the client sends a **timestamp** of the resource.
2. **If-Modified and If-None-Modified**, where the client sends an **ETag** representation of the resource.

In both cases, the client sends a piece of information it has about the resource, which allows the server to determine whether the resource has changed since the client last saw it. The server then decides whether to execute the request depending on the conditional header supplied by the client.

I don't understand why two separate approaches are available. Surely, ETags supersede timestamps, since the server could quite easily choose to generate ETags from timestamps.

So, my questions are:

- In which scenarios might you favour If-Unmodified-Since/If-Modified-Since over ETags?
- In which scenarios might you need both?

Comment: Though potentially tangential, there is another way to make a conditional request:  If-Range.  It can use an ETage or a timestamp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I once pondered the same thing, and realized that there is one difference that is quite important: Dates can be ordered, ETags can not.

This means that if some resource was modified a year ago, but never since, and we know it. Then we can correctly answer an If-Unmodified-Since request for arbitrary dates the last year and agree that sure... it has been unmodified since that date.

An Etag is only comparable for identity. Either it is the same or it is not. If you have the same resource as above, and during the year the docroot has been moved to a new disk and filesystem, giving all files new inodes but preserving modification dates. And someone had based the ETags on file's inode number. Then we can't say that the old ETag is still okay, without having a log of past-still-okay-ETags.

So I don't see them as one obsoleting the other. They are for different situations. Either you can easily get a Last-Modified date of all the data in the page you're about to serve, or you can easily get an ETag for what you will serve.

If you have a dynamic webpage with data from lots of db lookups it might be difficult to tell what the Last-Modified date is without making your database contain lots of modification dates. But you can always make an md5 checksum of the result rendered page.

When supporting these cache protocols I definitely go for only one of them, never both.

Comment: Upvoted, that's a really good point.

But is it always true that ETags are only comparable for identity? Doesn't that depend on what the server uses as Etag values? For example, as I understand it, a server could choose to use raw timestamps as ETags for some resources. This way, the ETags would be ordered for those resources.

So if ETags can effectively *be* timestamps, what is the point of a separate pair of header that only work with timestamps?

Comment: You need to add proxies into the equation. If your Etag values have semantic meaning, they dont now about it.

Answer (score 4):

There is one rather big difference: I can only use ETags if I have already asked the server for one in the past. Timestamps, OTOH, I can make up as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

Simple reason: backward-compatibility.

Comment: Ok. Are you saying that If-Unmodified-Since and If-Modified-Since are legacy, and therefore in a scenario where you have full control over the headers sent by the client and the headers processed by the server, you should only use ETags?

Comment: For validation and/or conditional requests, ETag is the way to go. However, Last-Modified headers have semantic meaning outside of conditional requests and should be sent too if you have control over everything. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.4